# How push to Bitbucket from PhpStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm, bitbucket, push, jetbrains-ide

How push to Bitbucket from PhpStorm? I see in PhpStorm the change history in git, but does not push changes from PhpStorm to Bitbucket.

I install/have:

> - Mac, PhpStorm 2018.1.4
> - account Bitbucket, and create my repositories
> - install SourceTree, work fine
> - install PhpStorm
> - install git
> - install plugin Bitbucket Linky

If I > chosen file > git > repository > push - I see in Event log

> 9:59  Push successful: Everything is up-to-date

console

> 09:59:56.649: [62.109.4.246] git -c core.quotepath=false -c
>   log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain bitbucket.org
>   refs/heads/master:master --tags To
>   https://bitbucket.org/account/repository.git
>   = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [up to date] Done

but there are no changes in Bitbucket

My screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F1zo.jpg

Comment: Did you commit the changes first?

Comment: I made changes in the file > saved > checked that downloaded via FTP to the server and saved locally. Did PUSH, but for BitBucket there is no change. However, if you start SourceTree and Push, the changes will go to BitBucket. The tests were done several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a solution: git > commit file > commit and push(not send commit) > Push

Answer (score 1):

Git push is intended to put to the remote your COMMITS, not uncommitted local change. So before pushing you need to commit changes. Otherwise, there is indeed nothing to push.

PHPStrom offers you to push right after commit with the Commit nad Push action in the commit dialog.